# Status of a Sayyad/Syed/Sayyid (a descendant from the family of the Holy Prophet [pbuh])?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sayyid

> **Sayyads (descendants from the family of the Holy Prophet, pbuh)** are entitled to more respect, though they are equal in the eyes of Allah. Giving them Sadaqah (Charity) is also forbidden.

What are the other rights of a Sayyad a **non-Sayyad** must remember?

Does this concept of Sayyads not **divide** the Muslims, and create kibr(feeling of lordliness) among (modern) Sayyads?

**Reference to Holy Scriptures** is highly appreciated.

**Jazaakallah...**

Comment: Where did you get your initial quote from? Is it from Wikipedia?

Comment: Didn't notice your comment for 3 months... LOL... No, I heard it from a scholar.

Comment: 'heard from a scholar' is not a reference at all. Either provide a Verse of Quran, Hadith or link to the page where someone said it. Also how do you see it in relation to Surah 11 Verse 46 where God told Prophet Noah that his son is from him because of his actions.

Answer (score 1):

**According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence):**

Sayyed can receive Sadaqah only from Sayyed. Also only Wajib Sadaqah like Zikat Fitrah and Zikat of property and Khums are banned to Sayyids. And they can receive Mustahab Sadaqah.

> **Question :**
>
> Is it permissible for a "Sayyid" to have Sadaqa for their needs? If it
>   is permissible, then please specify the condition.
>
> **Answer :**
>
> It is permissible for a Hashimi to give his sadaqa to another Hashimi
>   or to a non-Hashimi. This includes both Zakat of property and zakat of
>   Fitra. But it is not permissible for a non-Hashimi to give his Sadaqa
>   to a Hashimi. If a Hashimi receives Zakat of property or fitra from a
>   non-Hashimi, it would be forbidden for him to use it, and he who gives
>   it (zakat), his "Zimma" (obligation) would not be discharged. In cases
>   other than those mentioned above it is permissible for a non-Hashimi
>   to give his Sadaqa, atonement, or Fidya of fast ( kaffara) or any
>   desirable charity to a Hashimi. Yes, if charity given to a Hashimi is
>   too little an amount of property and it is given with the intention of
>   repulsing calamity and evil, there is Ishkaal (objection) in its being
>   permissible.

It does not make Kibr. Because they have more responsibility and more punish for sin.

The Prophet said:
Respect my children who are good for Allah and who are evil for me.

---

**References and further info and reasoning:**

[Official website of Grand Ayatollah Sistani](http://sistani.org/index.php?p=855722&id=1358) (no.4)

[Sadaqa For Syeds Is Haraam?](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/index.php?/topic/234973112-sadaqa-for-syeds-is-haraam/page__p__2008862__hl__sadaqa%20syed__fromsearch__1#entry2008862)

[Why Does It Matter If Someone Is Syed Or Not?](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/index.php?/topic/234934177-why-does-it-matter-if-someone-is-syed-or-not/)

Comment: Why wouldn't having more responsibility produce Kibr? If anything, it would justify it.

Comment: @Muz why would have? prophet SAWW had highest responsibility. they are irrelevant. Kibr is for obeying Satan and not for responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys, but where is this information coming from? I don't think that this was revealed in the Quran, neither was is it said by the Prophet (SAW).

This is the problem with a lot of different "branches" of Islam. Some people start following and adoring a fellow human being, and forget that Muhammad (SAW) was the last prophet. This is Bid'a.

The term "sayyid" is mostly used in Sufism. In Morocco, for example, people go to this place called Zawiyah where they meet a man called Sidi Hamza and kiss his hand, asking him to bless them. In my humble opinion, this is Bid'a because instead of turning directly to Allah, they ask this man instead.

I ask Allah to guide is to the right way and protect us from the misguiding whispers of shaytan.

EDIT:

Also, stories of slaves that were pious Muslims, Bilal for example, were revealed in the Quran and thus refute this whole concept that a person can have an "innate status". What raises your status in this world and the Hereafter is how pious you are. And still, that doesn't entitle anyone to "perks".

Besides, a pious person wouldn't even look for them.

Salam